# Python SGP4 1.1 Calculating Incorrect Orbit

Tags: python, orbit, propagation, orbital-mechanics, sgp4

I am using the python SGP4 1.1 module to calculate the position and velocity of a MEO satellite.  I'm noticing when compared against STK and JSatTrak that the returned values for position and velocity are incorrect. The Satellite should have a ground repeat track of roughly 6 hours, but this program is showing a ground repeat of 4:47:51. Is there something that I am doing incorrectly?

```
from sgp4.earth_gravity import wgs72
from sgp4.io import twoline2rv
from math import atan2, cos, pi, sin, sqrt, tan
from datetime import datetime

def calculate(options):
    x = options[0]
    y = options[1]
    z = options[2]

    # Constants (WGS ellipsoid)
    a = 6378.137
    e = 8.1819190842622e-2
    # Calculation
    b = sqrt(pow(a,2) * (1-pow(e,2)))
    ep = sqrt((pow(a,2)-pow(b,2))/pow(b,2))
    p = sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2))
    th = atan2(a*z, b*p)
    lon = atan2(y, x)
    lat = atan2((z+ep*ep*b*pow(sin(th),3)), (p-e*e*a*pow(cos(th),3)))
    n = a/sqrt(1-e*e*pow(sin(lat),2))
    alt = str(p/cos(lat)-n)
    lat = str((lat*180)/pi)
    lon = str((lon*180)/pi)
    #print "%s %s %s" % (lat, lon, alt)
    return (lat, lon, alt)

line1 = '1     1U 001001   14001.00000000  .00000000  00000+0  00000+0 0 00022'           
line2 = '2     1   0.0891 294.8098 0002843  64.8653   0.5014  5.00115502    09'

satellite = twoline2rv(line1, line2, wgs72)
position1, velocity1 = satellite.propagate(2013, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1)
position2, velocity2 = satellite.propagate(2013, 3, 1, 4, 47, 52)
lat1,lon1,alt1 = calculate(position1)
lat2,lon2,alt2 = calculate(position2)

print lat1 + " " + lon1  + " " + alt1
print lat2 + " " + lon2  + " " + alt2
print "\n\n"
print position1
print position2
```

Answer (score 4):

It's been three weeks since you asked this question so I suppose it won't help you but anyway, for the archives...

I don't have the Python SGP4 routines and I cannot test them, but usually SGP4 routines will return position and speed in an inertial (non-rotating) reference frame called TEME (True Equator, Mean Equinox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial#TEME). You are calculating the lat/long of Earth in this reference system, and it will give you wrong results. You should first transform the TEME system to a rotating system that rotates with Earth (like ECEF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF ) and then you can calculate the lat/lon.

I hope there are libraries for this conversion, as it is not a trivial one.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow for the rotation of the Earth in your calculations.  Instead of longitude you have calculated geocentric right ascension.  Start by reading the article on [Hour Angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour_angle) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified Deep Space Perturbations (SDP) models apply to objects with an orbital period greater than 225 minutes, which corresponds to an altitude of 5,877.5 km, assuming a circular orbit. As a result, you have to use SDP4 or SDP8 for MEO satellites.